# Разница между mysqli_fetch_assoc и mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php

Они вроде как оба возвращают ассоциативный массив В чем разница

Comment: В mysqli_fetch_array есть второй параметр - тип возвращаемого массива. В mysqil_fetch_assoc тип массива жёстко задан

Comment: Это более ясно если при выводе информации , к примеру $result['username']; это и есть ...assoc  или $result['0']; ...array

Answer (score -2):

mysqli_fetch_array вернет массив в основе которых модут числовые ключи а не имя колонок, но этот момент можно исправить вторым агрументом.

mysqil_fetch_assoc вернет массив где ключи уже предопределены как название колонок в базе.

Другими словами mysqli_fetch_array более гибкий.

Comment: Не стоит отвечать, если вы не владеете вопросом