# Подробная разница между mysqli_fetch_assoc и mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

Здесь вроде как бы есть ответ на этот вопрос
[Разница между mysqli_fetch_assoc и mysqli_fetch_array](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/923161/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-mysqli-fetch-assoc-%d0%b8-mysqli-fetch-array)

НО не могу разобраться в таком нюансе:

```
$connection = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);

$query = "SELECT * FROM classics";

$result = $connection->query($query);

$rows= $result->num_rows;

for($i = 0; $i < $rows; ++$i){

    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    echo 'Author: '  . $row['author'] .'<br>';
    echo 'Title: '   . $row['title'] .'<br>';
    echo 'Category: '. $row['category'] .'<br>';
}

$result->close();

$connection->close();
```

Работает только с функцией fetch_array, если вставить функцию fetch_assoc данные не отображаются. Хотя по логике fetch_assoc должен вытягивать тот же ассоциативный массив что и fetch_array с параметром MYSQLI_ASSOC. Но не работает. Хочется понять почему?

Comment: Проверьте что находится в $row. var_dump($row).

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Была синтаксическая ошибка - функции работают одинаково.